# How to save a random date generated from __RandomDate(,2024-01-30,2024-02-10,,) function in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to save a random date generated from __RandomDate(,2024-01-30,2024-02-10,,) function in jmeter, so that i can use the same date in the subsequent requests. Can someone please help on this !

I have tried with groovy but no luck. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter if the [__RandomDate() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomDate) is the name of [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) to store the generated value, just provide it like:

```
${__RandomDate(,2024-01-30,2024-02-10,,date)}
```

and you will be able to refer generated value as `${date}` where required:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)